# El codigo me funciona en sublimetext pero no en vs code

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode, sublimetext

Antes programaba en sublimetext y me cambie a vs code hace poco, la cosa esque estoy intentando crear una interfaz grafica en vscode con python y no logro hacer que cargue la imagen, aqui esta el codigo y el error.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

miFrame=Frame(root, width=500, height=400)

miFrame.pack()

miImagen=PhotoImage(file="mouse.png")

miLabeL = Label(miFrame, image=miImagen).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "mouse.png": no such file or directory

Pero si cargo ese codigo con sublimetext si me reconoce la imagen y funciona el programa pero con vscode no, a que se debe??

Comment: Sería conveniente que mostraras la terminal de VS Code en dónde corriste el archivo py y cómo se encuentra tu sistema de archivos (los paths del archivo py y de la imagen).

Answer (score 0):

No importa mucho que la imagen esté en la misma carpeta que el script, cuando llamas al archivo así sin una ruta, Python supone que está en la misma carpeta en la que estabas trabajando cuando comenzaste el script.  Por ejemplo, si tanto el script como la imagen están en la carpeta temporal, y comenzó su script de esta manera:

```
python temp / script.py
```

El intérprete no se da cuenta de que blueface.png también está en temp y lo busca en la carpeta en la que estaba, en este caso el padre de temp

Lo que debes hacer es usar rutas absolutas o usar el archivo__file __ para obtener primero la dirección completa del script.  Por ejemplo:

```
photo = PhotoImage (file = '/ absolute / path / to / image / blueface.png')
```

O usando la ubicación del script actual para construir la ruta de la imagen:

```
importar os
 base_folder = os.path.dirname (__ file__)
 image_path = os.path.join (base_folder, 'blueface.png')
 photo = PhotoImage (archivo = ruta_imagen)
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Si me instale la extension, en todo lo demas funciona muy bien el editor vscode pero para cargar imagenes no hay caso, ni con el codigo mas simple me funciona pero con sublime text funciona perfecto..., y si lo tengo en el directorio correcto asi que no puede ser eso :/

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda bro! Pero no entendi muy bien lo que me intentaste decir, aunque intente hacer algo con eso que dijiste de que "Python supone que está en la misma carpeta en la que estabas trabajando cuando comenzaste el script" y cree un script nuevo en vscode con una imagen y todo en la misma carpeta y nada me sigue marcando que hay en un error en cargar, y para variar en sublime y en la consola de cmd si me cargan las imagenes y me lanza la interfaz